# Using cons, list, append in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I need to write a code that take a element and add to list that give as input, and return an new list instead of old list.. after than i will do recurssion and i need new list... below code is working fine.. however i try to reduce all set! that because confuse me and sometime i take error that i cannot solve..

How can i do this operation without set! ? I try just cons, list and append but none of them do this job.

```
(set! list (cons element list))
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `(cons element list)` is enough.

Your code is altering the contents of `list` variable. We don't normally do that, in functional style, and the only way to do this is to use `set!` as you did.

But to just return the new list, which has a new element on top of it, the call `(cons element list)` is enough:

```
...
(let ((newlist (cons element oldlist)))
  .....
  ..... use newlist and oldlist as needed
```

Comment: that's what the call `(cons e l)` does. It returns new list. If you need it in a function, write: `(define (add e l) (cons e l))` and call it `.... (add e l) ...`. But then you can just call `... (cons e l) ...` instead.